# How to prompt user to input mysql connection strings in a setup

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-setup-proje

I created a system from visual studio where it works with a mysql database. I wants to create a deployment project where the user can input mysql connection strings in the setup where the program will use them when ever it wants to connect to the database

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to know if it can be done? Or how to do it? Or do you want some codez from somebody?

Comment: addin express installers may help you

Comment: Hi yu_ominae, actually I wants to know how to do it.